# google script to send conditional email

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to run a script on a google sheet to send an email only if a certain column does not equal "y".   If that's true, then I want it to send the email and then put a "y" in the column to prevent sending a duplicate.  This is not working though - I keep getting duplicate emails sent.  Here's the code:

```
 function sendEmails() {   
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   var startRow = 2;    // First row of data to process   
   var numRows = 600;   // Number of rows to process   
   // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3   
   var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 600) 
   //Fetch values for each row in the Range.   
   var data = dataRange.getValues();   
   for (i in data) {
     var row = data[i];
     if (row[19]!= 'y') {
       var emailAddress = "xxx@xxx.com"; // First column
       var message = "A new trip request has been submitted.  Here's what you need to know.  Trip #: " + row[1] + " " + row[4] + " to:" +
 row[10] + " Depart Date: " + row[8];       // Second column
       var subject = "New Trip Request  " + row[1];
       MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
       sheet.getRange(i+2,19).setValue('y');
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: There is a possibility that you are referring to wrong column number in this line of code 'if (row[19]!= 'y') {'.

Comment: It was replacing the column header with a y in column 19 but I think I fixed that.  So I'm pretty sure 19 is the right one.

Comment: By the way, I ran your code once, and it maxed out the number of emails my account could send in one day from one execution of your code.  It's trying to send something like 600 emails because the `FOR` loop evaluates to true on every iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition checking for a "y" value has a hard coded value:

```
if (row[19]!= 'y') {
```

Replace the 19 with "i"

```
if (row[i]!= 'y') {
```

Comment: Can you help me understand what that will do?  Column 19 is the column I want it to look in.

Comment: The `row` variable is taking a two dimensional array of values when it is first initialized.  [Documentation - getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())  So, your `row` variable defaults to being an array type variable.  It's indexed by ROW first!  See the documentation.  So when you hard code the number 19, it's not checking what data was in column 19, it's checking what data was in row 20 on every iteration of the `FOR` loop.  It's zero indexed starting at [0][0].  So Row 1 is index zero.

Comment: Something I don't get here. var Data is the 2d array, then when the loop starts, the var row is data[i]: so a 1d array with the values of every row. Then if one wants to check the column 19 for a certain value, why shouldn't  if(row[18]='y') be correct ?

Comment: There are probably blank values getting put into the second dimension.  To know for sure what is happening, you need to print the values to the LOG.  Put in a Logger.log statement into your code: `Logger.log("The value of row[19] is: " + row[19]);` and see what the value is on every iteration.  Then do the same thing, but with a different value, for other parts of the code.  That way you don't need to imagine or guess at what is happening, you will see exactly what values are being returned.

Comment: @Sandy Good: so it seems my previous comment was correct ?

Answer (score 0):

As KRR already suggested, if you want to check col19 of your spreadsheet, in your (zero-indexed) 2d-array returned by .getValues() you'll have to use:

```
if (row[18]!= 'y') {
```

This line:

```
sheet.getRange(i+2,19).setValue('y');
```

sets a 'y' in column 19 of your spreadsheet. I assume that is correct ?

Comment: I already had the same condition in another section of script, so I  moved this send email part under that and got the result I wanted.

Comment: The spreadsheet collects form responses - transportation requests.  When the request comes in, the sheet puts the request on the transportation calendar and emails the office staff (so long as the request did not come from one of us).  After the trip, the costs get put into the sheet and an email receipt is sent to the requestor (again, only if the requestor is not one of us).  Considering that I didn't even know what script was before this week, I'm pretty happy that I was able to put this together.  Many thanks to the stackoverflow community.